# Branch created in bitbucket does not shown in my local git even after git fetch

Tags: git, eclipse, bitbucket

In our company we have a branch for every Sprint.
When sprint ends, I switch to master and merge branch back into master from Eclipse git.

Team -> merge -> Local -> Sprint-1 ...
Team -> push to upstream.

Then I go to BitBucket and create a new branch. Sprint-2 
Branch is created and work collegue can see it and use it, but for some reason I cannot see branch.

Elcipse pull says everything is up to date.

From console:

```
$ git fetch && git checkout Sprint-2
error: pathspec 'Sprint-2' did not match any file(s) known to git

$ git pull origin
Already up to date.
```

If I export project as new in Eclipse, then branch suddenly appears. 
But it is not very convenient.

Comment: Run `git config remote.origin.fetch` in the console and see what it prints.

Comment: `git fetch origin Sprint-2:Sprint-2`

Comment: @ElpieKay

`>git config remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/text_constants_to_file:refs/remotes/origin/text_constants_to_file`

Comment: Lookes like @phd method worked.

Comment: @Martins you can run `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` so that `git fetch && git checkout <newbranch>` will work for future new branches.